# DataGrid data bindings with ADO.net Entity Data Model

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have an Entity Data Model-based app that uses SQL Server CE 3.5 as its data store.

Inside the database, I have some *customers* each of which has some *orders*. This is a simplified overview:

[image]

In my WPF Window, I inserted a `DataGrid` in which I would like to list all *customers*, with their name and address. Something like this:

[image]

So I wrote this XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="customersDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Window_Drop" DragEnter="Window_DragEnter">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But now, how can I connect the column **Name** with the property `Name` of the customers in my data model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using DataGridTemplateColumn, you can put DataTemplate there.. (Note: you might not need "data:" prefix. )

```
 <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate> 
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried but it still does not work. No errors, no exceptions. May I have to tell to the XAML, in some ways, _what is the context to use_? How can I do it?

Comment: @Dev The reason why it isn't working is because your datagridview isn't actually bound to the datasource. You need to query the database, and put the results in a `List<Customer>`. Expose this list as a property in the code behind and bind to it using the code `DataGrid.ItemsSource={Binding ListOfCustomers}` inside the datagrid in xaml. Preferably you would use a framework called MVVM with your WPF application. If you use this framework your code will be amazing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I have created the property `customersList` (`private List<Customer>`). I valued it in the `Window_Loaded` method. I verified that `customersList` contains the correct values. Then, I added the attribute `ItemsSource="{Binding customersList}"` to the `DataGrid` tag in the XAML. I forgot something?

Comment: The Window_Loaded event takes place after the binding is resolved. This means you either have to a) Give values to the customersList well before the loaded (do it in the constructor to make sure) or b) Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, which will tell the xaml to get a new value from the property every time the property changes. option a) will take the least amount of time, but option b is the best if you want to have the list change alot. It seems like alot of work, but trust me, it saves you tons of time in the long run, especially if your program is even semi-complicated.

Comment: @Dev did you sort your problem out? I can make some code for you if you like